# Image not shown ckeditor5

Tags: image, ckeditor5

I have insert an image link i ckeditor5 and the image is displayed perfectly in editor
[image]

but after submit the image is not displayed in the topic
[image]

How can i resolve this problem
All files are updated and the editor is builded perfectly

image not shown in topic